# Is there a way to make access to the wider internet dependent on accessing it through a VPN like hotspot shield?

Tags: vpn

I connect to the wider internet through a commercial VPN (HotSpot Shield). I'd like to prevent myself from inadvertently connecting when I haven't noticed that the connection to the VPN is down.

I've seen some options in network-settings that allow the user to configure the computer to connect through a VPN, which suggested to me that there might be a way to make access to the wider internet require access to it through a VPN.

Is there a way to do that? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Does the program you use to connect to the VPN offer this functionality.  The VPN i use has their own client, within that program, is a program that watches for specific applications are ran and generates a notification if I cam not connected to the VPN when those programs are ran.

Comment: @Ramhound "Does the program you use to connect to the VPN offer this functionality" It's not obvious from the client interface. 
"generates a notification if I am not connected to the VPN when those programs are ran" My client does do something similar, but I'm trying to configure something that stops it entirely.